# Can we verify whether a typedef has been defined or not

Tags: c

Suppose my program is:

```
typedef int MYINT;

int main()  
{  
    MYINT x = 5;  
    ........  
    do_something()    
    ........    
    /* I wanna test whether MYINT is defined or not */
    /* I can't use: ifdef (MYINT), since MYINT is not a macro */

    ........
    return 0;
}
```

Actually, I encountered this problem while I was using a cross-compiler for vxworks. The cross-compiler header file included: typedef int INT.

But, my stack's header file used:

```
 #ifndef INT  
 #define int INT
```

Can you please suggest how to test typedefs, whether they are defined previously or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder if there's some hideous hack with `sizeof` and undeclared function calls that could distinguish whether a type name exists...

Comment: @R.. - If there was, it'd probably be decently well known by now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Your best option is to use `typedef` yourself, since redefinition of a `typedef` is an error.

```
#ifdef INT
# error "No, we want to define INT!"
#endif

typedef int INT;  // error if previously typedef'd
```

(I suppose you didn't really want to `#define int INT` :)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can.

`typedef` is just a *typename alias* for the compiler.

Comment: Erm 'typename alias'?  And in italics?  ;)   It's more like "a synonym for another type".

Comment: My point about the use of `typename alias` is that it implies that this is the usual or possibly standard based terminology (which for the latter is definitely not the case).  You are also mixing two C++ concepts (in the case of C++'11 anyway) that have completely different meanings.  But these comments at least will now help to clarify things.

Comment: It's not "standard terminology" in C either.  C++ inherited the 'synonym' terminology from C.  But of course you can continue to argue technicalities and just ignore my comments rather than improving your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a typedef because C doesn't have any [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) capability.

All I can suggest is that you use #define as suggested by @larsmans.

```
#define MYINT int
...
#ifdef MYINT
  // MYINT is defined
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

No, in C you cannot do this directly. However you can use `#ifdef` to check whether a name is already defined or not.